# Вопросительные знаки в консоли. Почему вместо того что в переменной мне выводи вопросительный знак?

Tags: c#

[image: Вот что выводит у меня в консоль]

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "Семейная компания дяди развивается с завидным успехом";
        int space = 0;
        int upper = 0;
        int lower = 0;
        double pr = str.Length / 100;
        for (int i = 0; i<str.Length; i++)
        {
            if(str[i] == ' ')
            {
                space++;
            }
            else if(str[i].ToString() == str[i].ToString().ToLower())
            {
                lower++;
            }

        }
        upper = str.Length - lower - space;
        double prup = upper / pr;
        double prlw = lower / pr;
        Console.WriteLine($"Строчных букв {prup}% а прописных {prlw}%");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Это знак бесконечности, просто его не поддерживает кодировка консоли**, похоже у тебя `pr = 0`, поэтому x / 0 = `∞`.
(int / int) выдаст целое число. То есть:
`99 / 100 = 0`
`100 / 100 = 1`
`178 / 100 = 1`
У тебя str.Length менее 100, поэтому ( x < 100) / 100  выдаёт 0, в конце концов что выдаёт "∞", а консоль "?".
Вообще то, что ты хочешь сделать делается по другому.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "Семейная компания дяди развивается с завидным успехом";
    int up = str.ToString().Where(z => char.IsUpper(z)).Count();
    int down = str.ToString().Where(z => char.IsLower(z)).Count();
    double percentUp = (double)100 * up / (up + down);
    Console.WriteLine($"Заглавных букв - {Math.Round(percentUp, 2)}%,\nПрописных - {Math.Round(100 - percentUp, 2)}%.");
}
/*
str.ToString() - Выдаст new char[] { 'С', 'е', 'м', 'е'...}.
Where - выбирает из этого char[] только то, что подходит нам, в первом случае char.IsUpper(char), а во втором IsLower(char) и возвращает IEnumerable<char>.
Count - метод или свойство, 
в IEnumerable - метод
в List - свойство
отвечающее за количество элементов в массиве.
Чтобы получить процент заглавных букв нужно по форуме 100 * (x+y) / x
А чтобы строчных просто 100 - количество заглавных
Math.Round(num, d) - округляет в верх, где num - число, а d - количество цифр после запятой
*/
```

Comment: Спасибо проблема теперь понятно попробую решить. Ваше решение скорее всего работает, но если я не ошибаюсь оно на С++ так как  с Where я в принципе не встречался. Ну или мы пока просто не прошли эту тему

Comment: @Senmonti, В C++ main выглядит по другому, в C++, как и в других ЯП нет такого крутого Linq в нативной библиотеке, как в C# <3

Comment: Значит пока не разбирали. Еще раз спасибо. проблему я смог решить.